# Problema al acceder al método de enfoque en Ionic Vue con TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, ionic

Estoy enfrentando un problema al intentar acceder al método de enfoque (setFocus()) en un componente Ionic Vue utilizando TypeScript. He estado utilizando las referencias de elementos (ref) en Vue para acceder a los elementos DOM, pero parece que la implementación de Ionic Vue presenta algunas advertencias en este caso.

```
<template>
  <IonPage>
    <IonContent>
      <IonInput ref="inputPassword" type="password" />
    </IonContent>
  </IonPage>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { IonInput, onIonViewDidEnter, IonPage, IonContent } from "@ionic/vue"
import { ref } from "vue"

const passwordInput = ref<HTMLIonInputElement | null>(null)

onIonViewDidEnter(() => {
  if (passwordInput.value) {
    const nextInput = passwordInput.value;
    nextInput.setFocus(); // El método setFocus no existe en TypeScript
    nextInput.$el.setFocus(); // Funciona, pero TypeScript muestra una advertencia
  }
});
</script>
```

He notado que, aunque $el funciona para acceder al método setFocus(), TypeScript muestra una advertencia debido a la propiedad $el que no está presente en los tipos.

Me gustaría saber si existe alguna forma recomendada de acceder directamente al método setFocus() en los componentes Ionic Vue utilizando TypeScript, sin necesidad de recurrir a nextInput.$el.setFocus() ni a @ts-ignore.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda o orientación que puedan proporcionar. ¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Estás intentando llamar al método `setFocus` en la variable incorrecta: passwordInput es el elemento input, nextInput es el valor (un string) introducido

Comment: nextInput lo declaro para acceder al elemento de forma reactiva en vue usando .value
const nextInput = passwordInput.value;

Comment: Correcto, pero lo que quiero decir es que el método setFocus() debe existir en passwordInput, no en nextInput